# How to disable all the controls on windows phone by displaying a semi transparent control over the page?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I'd like to have some sort of semi transparent/translucent effect displayed over the entire page and then display my option buttons on top of it but I just can't figure out how and it's driving me nuts! I've seen it in plenty of wp8 apps so it is doable but I just don't know how!

Once this semi transparent/translucent effect is displayed, I want it to dissapeared if clicked on or if one of my option buttons is clicked, and restore the screen as it was or execute an action accordingly.

I've somehow managed to do it by setting the Background colors using a storyboard but strangely enough, once displayed and my options buttons appear, they look fine but once the storyboard is completed, the button then look disabled as well which just looks wrong!!

What is the proper way to give a "Disabled" effect as if you had a semi transparent dialog box displayed over a window.

Any ideas, suggestions or code would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to set IsEnabled to FALSE?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, I think the OP wants to create an overlay. You can do so, by positioning (and initially hiding) your "prompt" panel alongside your "content" panel. The "prompt" panel should have a higher zindex and probably a White background with opacity of, say, 0.7. Then the overlay would effectively disable click events on controls that are below it, until you dismiss it.

Comment: If my buttons are in the overlay, they will also look disabled due to the opacity, so how do I get opaque buttons in semi transparent prompt panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be making this more complicated than it needs to be. Consider the following XAML for example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot">
    ...
  </Grid>

  <Grid x:Name="ContentOverlay" Background="#AA000000" Visibility="Collapsed">
    ...
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Both ContentRoot and ContentOverlay will anchor at the top left of the LayoutRoot grid and span the row height. They will stack from furthest to closest in order of declaration, so ContentRoot will be rendered beneath ContentOverlay. Simply manipulate the Visibility of ContentOverlay based on user input.

Alternatively, you can set the Opacity for ContentOverlay to 0 along with collapsed visibility (required so it doesn't intercept hits to the ContentRoot child controls below) and fade it in and out using storyboarding in Blend. That probably looks like a slightly cleaner transition to a user, even if it's only 0.3 seconds long or so.

Comment: @NewDev, lthibodeaux I did what you both suggested but I had to move the grid that contains my "option buttons" in the overlay but they also look disabled. How can I get around this? This is pretty much what I had and as mentioned originally when I used a storyboard, the buttons appear enabled until it is completed and then somehow they dim to the same level as the overlay panel. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Opacity of the overlay should be 100%, so check your final keyframes to make sure you're not setting it to anything lower after the animation is complete. You should "dim" the background color attribute only. Notice in the example above the background has around 65% opacity given its alpha values.

Comment: may be I'm missing something, but wouldn't setting the opacity to 100% make it totally opaque and therefore none of my controls behind would be visible? Can you exclude the storyboard out of this and not include animation in the process just to simplify things for now? I'm trying to get a similar effect to the Weave app if that helps? I've got the animation sorted, but I'm struggling with this. Maybe you could have a look at it as it may help understand better what I'm trying to achieve. Once on an article, flick from right to left and you'll see the buttons appear.

Comment: I didn't say storyboarding was necessary. As I mentioned the simple interaction is toggling visibility. However, to clarify the opacity behavior: just try it for one. The grid background color is 65% opaque (#AA in the alpha color value) in the above sample, and the controls on it are 100% opaque by default. 100% of 65% background opacity is still 65%. 65% opacity of 65% would be closer to 42% opacity.

Comment: only took me a year to get back to this, but I finally understand what you mean and it is working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Blend to specify VisualStates (View | States. Then 'states' tab.) You can switch between states in code behind using VisualStateManager.GoToState. One state would be normal, the other all controls disabled.
Mike